# Limit value sent to API

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I want to limit the value a user can send to an API, for example, Users can only send the value of 30

By using `minlength="" maxlength=""` I can limit the number of chars typed but I cannot, for example, stop the user from entering 9999999 and overloading the results or not getting a result.

```
<input type="number" id="passlen" class="pass-len-box" min="4" max="20" placeholder="Enter password length"
        required>
```

Using `type="number"` will stop user inputting Text but it will still pass lower values (`min="5" max="20"`) I can still pass 1,2,3,4, and 1234

```
 <input id="passlen" class="pass-len-box" minlength="3" maxlength="20" placeholder="Enter password length"
        required>
      <button class="generatorPass" id="genratorPass">Generate</button>
      <p id="dispPassword"></p>
```

```
document.querySelector("#genratorPass").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const user_input_text = document.querySelector("#passlen");
  request(
    user_input_text
  );
});

const passworldEl = document.getElementById("dispPassword");

request = (
  user_input_text,
 
) => {
  let url = `https://passwordwolf.com/api/?length=${user_input_text.value}&repeat=1`;
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      for (let { password } of responseJson) {
        const apipass = document.createElement("p");
        apipass.innerText = password;
        document.querySelector("#dispPassword").innerHTML = password;
        console.log(password);
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: Use a [number input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) instead, and use [`max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#max)?

Comment: can share with us few inputs to test? Only negative scenario

Comment: Good thinking, I tried that before and while it can stop users entering letters etc It will still pass lower values (min="5" max="20") I can still pass 1,2,3,4, and 1234

Comment: @evolutionxbox: with regards to the number input, the latest (as of writing) Stack Overflow blog: “[Why the number input is the worst input](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/09/15/why-the-number-input-is-the-worst-input/).” Dominic, are you hosting the end-point or is that a remote service? If you’re hosting, you can obviously cap the maximum, if you’re sending I think you’d have to intercept the request and replace invalid (below min, over max) values with an appropriate value.

Comment: @DavidThomas I read that when I was looking for past guidance, interesting indeed.
I am not hosting, I am sending the fetch to get the request. I wouldn't know where to start on how to do that but I can see that being the only solution If it can't be handled in HTML with input types and rules.

That's not too bad as I can include the bug in my documentation and fix it when I learn more.

Thank you

Comment: May I ask what you're intending to achieve with `request(user_input_text)`, the first argument passed to the [`request()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request) should be the url of a resource, not a DOM node, and in this case the DOM node is an `<input>`, so you'd (presumably) intend to use its `value` property instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out in your code:

As for your the description, you do want number that is greater then 30 to be displayed to user in input box. This code will help restrict user input to 30.

---

```js
  var input = document.querySelector("input");
  var state = { value: input.value };
  input.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
    if (input.value < 31 || event.key == "Backspace") {
      state.value = input.value;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML =
        "Alert !! Invalid Input : " + input.value;
      input.value = state.value;
    }
  });
```

```html
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter password length" />
  <h2>Input value less then 31 will be accepted</h2>
  <p id="alert" style="color:maroon"></p>
```